# How can border is bigger than div itself?

Tags: html, css

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
 #Tri{
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border-top: 50px solid yellow;
  border-right:50px solid red;
  border-bottom:50px solid green;
  border-left:50px solid blue;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="Tri"></div>
</body>
```

This is the code to draw four triangles, what I can't get it is that in this code, div's width is 0px but its border is 50px, how can it be?

Comment: I think you need to understand how the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `width` and `height` style only controls the inner `width` and `height` of the html element. While the border `weight` controls the outer part of the HTML element.

---

This one interprets that there is no space for the content

```
    #Tri{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top: 50px solid yellow;
    border-right:50px solid red;
    border-bottom:50px solid green;
    border-left:50px solid blue;
}
```

While this one interprets that there is space in the content that is why it stretches since the `div` element occupies the available `width` available.

```
    #Tri{
    border-top: 50px solid yellow;
    border-right:50px solid red;
    border-bottom:50px solid green;
    border-left:50px solid blue;
}
```

Reffering to the [**css box model**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Margin is applied first, to distance the element to the other objects in the html document. `Border` is then applied in which based on the example of the 4 colored triangles which are borders is displayed. `Padding` would then be applied to distance the content from the `border` and lastly the element content in which you set the it's style to `width:0px` and `height:0px` is only applied inside the `border`.

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  Here's an illustration of the CSS box model:

[image: css-box-model]
<sub>(source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/box-model.gif))</sub>

If you leave your content (meaning height and width) to 0, your border can still exist.  Learn more about the CSS box model at [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The "box model" in CSS is actually:

width + padding + border = actual width of box

height + padding + border = actual height of box

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the box-model by specifying `box-sizing`.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

should achieve the effect you want. It is also how Internet Explorer (used to?) apply the box-model.